# How to create Moq for "Update a property of concrete class in a method using injected interface method"

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, moq

I have this concrete class which implements an interface

```
internal interface ITableAdapter
{
  int CustomFill(Dataset dataset, ...);
}

internal interface IEntityRetriever
{
  IEntity RetriveEntity();
}
```

```
internal class RetriveEntityById: IEntityRetriever
{
  private readonly EntityDataSet _entityDataSet = new EntityDataSet();
  private readonly ITableAdapter _tableAdapter;

  public RetriveEntityById(ITableAdapter tableAdapter, ...)
  {
    _tableAdatper = tableAdapter; 
    ...
  }

  public Entity RetriveEntity()
  {
    var EntityModel = RetriveEntityModel();
    ...
    return EntityModel.Entity;
  }

  private EntityDataSet RetriveEntityModel()
  {
    _tableAdapter.CustomFill(_entityDataSet, ...);
    return _entityDataSet;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to unit test this class and couldn't figure how to mock the behaviour of `CustomFill` method which populate the private property of the concrete class.

```
var adapter = new Mock<ITableAdapter>();
adapter.Setup(x=>x.CustomFill(It.IsAny<DataSet>(), ...)).Returns(1)
```

Comment: The only that left is to pass this mock object to the `RetriveEntityById` class via its ctor: `var sut = new RetriveEntityById(adapter.Object, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up editing private property in the method set up lamda function

```
var adapter = new Mock<ITableAdapter>();
adapter.Setup(x=>x.CustomFill(It.IsAny<DataSet>(), ...))
   .Returns((Dataset ds, ..) => 
        {
            var row = ds.AddRow(...);
            return 1
        });
```